# hair particle went out from the eyes

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

hey all so I am trying to remove some hair particle from the eyes , I create vertex group and painting around the eyes , but as you can see there are stick hair coming out, even though I went to particle system -children - simple but I dont know the reason of why its coming out its not going I am painting  inside they eyes any tips? [image]

Comment: Have you used the vertex group in the particle settings for the hair density? The *Simple* children are placed around their parents within a given spheric radius. Therefore, they can still appear in areas where you don't want them. To prevent this try to reduce the area in the vertex group, reduce the radius, or try *Interpolated* children.

Comment: thanks dude i didnt know why i didnt think of going to vertex group and adjust/paint around it , it works thank u